# Get the name of workbook that hosts the currently running VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

I'll also note, that the `Application.Run("<workbook name>!<public VBA function name>")` allows jumps of the execution to other workbooks without changing the `ActiveWorkbook` property.

I want to know the name of the workbook which hosts the currently executing VBA code.

In case if someone did understand me wrong:

- The trivial `ActiveWorkbook` wouldn't do, because the active workbook might be completely different then the one, where the running VBA macro is located.
- The `Me` object isn't the ticket either. It contains the reference to the class which method is currently executing, regardless of the hosting object (it would work only if my VBA code is in a method of the Worksheet or Workbook class).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to know the name of the workbook which hosts the currently executing VBA code.

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Name
```

Comment: Works great. Confirmed. I'm so happy I don't have to play with VBIDE classes!